# Fires an Event of a Control present in DataTemplate Of ListBox using WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource BasicListBoxStyle}"  ItemsSource="{Binding TripAttributeOptions}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Description}" IsChecked="{Binding ExcludeVal, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                         <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.GroupCheckBoxCheckCommand}"></cmd:EventToCommand>
                     </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </CheckBox>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

There is a property bind to the checkbox of my Listbox datatemplate, when that prperty set to true, checkbox of listbox also get checked, now i want to execute a command through the event but it won't fire. Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EventToCommand` has always felt unnecessarily complex to me. Why do you want this to be a command?

Why not just call the command's execute method from within the setter of your `ExcludeVal` property, which is bound to `IsChecked`? Or have your view model watch its own `PropertyChanged` event and look for when the `ExcludeVal` property changes?

Comment: Actually i can't do that as my ExcudeVal property is a property in POCO entity. So i can't do this thing.

Comment: I would expect any property of your ViewModel that you're using in a Binding expression to at least raise the OnPropertyChanged event. If it doesn't, then I would wrap that property inside a new property in your ViewModel that does raise the event.

Comment: Then it might be a good idea to wrap your POCOs in a simple ViewModel class, say TripAttributeOptionViewModel. Alternatively, you could try out the CommandReference class (just Google it). I use it for stuff like this. It lets you reference a command outside of the data template (like in the data context of your window) by means of a StaticResource instead of a messy relative source binding.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the opening `{` in your `EventToCommand` `Command` binding expression:

Should be:

```
<cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.GroupCheckBoxCheckCommand}"></cmd:EventToCommand>
```